# issues with for loop syntax in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am a new learner and I had a problem with the syntax. I used

```
n=$1

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
do
   sum=$((sum+i))
done
echo $sum;
```

and it says that theres an error in line 6 . I donot know wha the error is and donot know how to resolve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (need to use double parentheses in for loop):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=$1

for ((i=0; i<n; i++))
do
   sum=$((sum+i))
done
echo $sum;
```